# What could be the basis for computing your Cost of Opportunity?

Tags: stocks, investing, savings

For example, I bought 30 shares of X Company for $10/share in November 2016:

```
30 x $10 = $300 
+ 10% tax = $330
```

If I hold on to it until 2021 and the price of each share is around $11.50,

1. Have I made a good investment or I have cost myself opportunity?
2. And compared to a time deposit or regular savings?

Comment: Where does the immediate 10% tax come from?  In the US, at least, you'd only pay *long term* capital gains tax of `15%` **on the profits** ($11.50 - $10.00 = $1.50) `30 x $1.50 x 15% = $6.75`, not $30.00.

Comment: Also, please add a country tag.  (The phrase "time deposit" makes me think you aren't American.)"

Comment: @RonJohn - and OP added the tax upfront. I wonder if there's a country that does it this way?

Answer (score 1):

> Have I made a good investment or I have cost myself opportunity?

A five year increase (presuming you held it until *November* 2021) of `15%` computes to a 2.83% CAGR (compound annual growth rate).

That's... **low** for a stock.  Even with COVID, the S&P500 has yielded a 14.23% CAGR from Nov 2016 until now.

*However*, with that low growth, I'd ask what dividends the company was issuing.  If, for example, they issued a $0.55 dividend every year, and you reinvested them into buying more shares, then your *true* yield would be about `7.8%`!!  That's quite acceptable, especially if the price is stable (didn't collapse last March).

Thus, based on your goals and risk tolerance, you **might** have made a poor investment, **or** you **might** have made a good investment.

(I wouldn't mind having such a stable stock with high dividend yield in my IRA...)

> And compared to a time deposit or regular savings?

According to [Bankrate.com](https://www.bankrate.com/banking/cds/historical-cd-interest-rates/), the **average**, five year CD in 2016 yielded about `0.8%.`  So, this investment is better than a time deposit.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing an investment to a typical alternative investment is called [hurdle rate analysis](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/finance/hurdle-rate-definition/) (or discount rate analysis). Choose a hurdle rate and then run the analysis to see how the investment compares to that hurdle rate.